# Cypress not connecting to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost, integration-testing, cypress

I have a docker compose file that holds my cypress container:

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379"
    # restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: ./.env
    # restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - postgres

  #access by going to localhost:16543
  #when adding a server to the serve list
  #the hostname is postgres
  #the username is postgres
  #the password is postgres
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file: ./.env
    # restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "16543:80"
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - pgadmin


  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev    # use docker-dev because production npm installs and npm builds
    command: python manage.py celery
    env_file: ./.env
    # restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - tmp:/tmp
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - celery

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - tmp:/tmp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: ./.env
    # restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - celery
      - pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - celery
      - pgadmin
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - web

  # Cypress container
  cypress:

    # the Docker image to use from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images
    image: "cypress/included:4.0.2"
    depends_on:
      - web
    environment:
      # pass base url to test pointing at the web application
      - CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://web:8000
    # share the current folder as volume to avoid copying
    working_dir: /e2e
    volumes:
      - ./:/e2e
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - cypress

volumes:
  pgdata:
  tmp:

networks:
  main:
```

For some reason when I start my server and then start cypress using `docker-compose up --exit-code-from cypress` I get the following error, that I cannot seem to debug, please note my server is running, and all are on the same network **main**

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://web:8000

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...

====================================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:    4.0.2                                                                              │
  │ Browser:    Electron 78 (headless)                                                             │
  │ Specs:      1 found (login/test.spec.js)                                                       │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                    
  Running:  login/test.spec.js                                                              (1 of 1)
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `yarn upgrade`


  Login Page

    1) Visits Page


  0 passing (671ms)
  1 failing

  1) Login Page Visits Page:
     CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

Common situations why this would fail:
  - you don't have internet access
  - you forgot to run / boot your web server
  - your web server isn't accessible
  - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer

The stack trace for this error is:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)
```

Comment: Also note that this occurs when I add the Cypress service to the main network.

Comment: Why won't you update post to add the main network to cypress if your real scenario is that? Additional, would you remove `restart: unless-stopped` of all service to confirm `web` is really start?

Comment: @atline the post has been updated, yes web is running, but Cypress  dies after failing to connect

Comment: any solution for that?